# Page does not load during download

Tags: php, apache, download, http2

since I changed my hoster, I have the problem that you can no longer surf on a page while downloading a file.
What's different is that the new server uses the HTTP2 protocol. It always runs over HTTPS. I suspect that this may be the reason?

The downloads are protected and will be started via POST request with the following function:

```
public static function download($file, $filename='') {
    if(file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
        $filename = $filename ? $filename : basename($file);
        $filename = File::ValidateFilename($filename);
        $mime     = mime_content_type($file);
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename);
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Does anyone else have the problem or does anyone know what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http/2 should not affect the application as far as I know in any way

Comment: Yes. But it hasn't worked since I moved my web server. That's the only difference I see. On the old server it worked wonderfully. You could download several files and continue surfing on the site, now you have to wait until you have finished a download.

Comment: Create a simple page with `<?php print phpinfo(); ?>`. Compare the versions, loaded libraries, etc.  Knowing what is different might help (if more than HTTP2).

Comment: I can't access the old server anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved it now:

The downloads are all available on the server and they were requested by post request and you can check if the user has the rights.

If one had clicked on Download, then PHP function (with header) the download was started. But because it was not possible to download and surf while one download was running.

Now the download is not started with a click on Download, but the Download ID and a Unique ID is stored in the database.

Before that I created several subdomains (mirror001.domain.tld, mirror002.domain.tld etc) and they all access my mirror script.

A click on the download button does not start the download, but saves the "permission" in the database and redirects it to a random mirror subdomain.

```
X = sprintf("%03d",mt_rand(1,50));
Location: mirrorX.domain.tld/UNIQUEID
```

The mirror script now uses the unique ID to check whether the download was generated and if so, the script deletes the entry from the database and starts the download. Because a download is always executed at a different distance, every visitor can now continue surfing on my site.